# Is there a way to get bot data using the bot token in discord API?

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, http-headers, discord, bearer-token

I'm trying to get information about a bot using the bot token, like the way to get user, passing on the header Authorization: Bearer ${userToken}. I'm sending a request to the route GET https://discord.com/api/oauth2/applications/@me passing on the header Authorization: Bearer ${botToken}, and the response is 401. But if I send a request to the route GET https://discord.com/api/oauth2/users/@me with my token in the header, I got my data. I don't have sure if the bot token can be used for this, I check on the docs, and I found this https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#get-current-application-information, but I don't understand what I need to pass in the header to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you're very close to the correct solution.

The issue is with the "Authorization" header, instead of "Bearer" you should use "Bot" when using a token for a bot user.

In your case the header should be:

```
Authorization: Bot ${botToken}
```

CURL example:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/applications/@me' \
--header 'Authorization: Bot <BOT TOKEN HERE>'
```

Regarding the question about "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/users/@me", try using "https://discord.com/api/users/@me" instead.